# Git ignore ignoring too many things

Tags: git, gitignore

I have `folder` and `src/folder`.  I want to ignore the former but not the latter, except `folder` in `.gitignore` ignores both.

Comment: Someone more knowledgeable than I am will surely pinpoint to what you have to write there but _probably_ you will add something like `!src/folder`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`folder` matches any file and directory named "folder" in any directory. Put a slash in front:

```
/folder
```

This only matches the directory in the root of your repository.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need a small change in your `.gitignore` file:

```
/folder
```

This will only ignore the folder named `folder` at the root directory. Without the `/` git by default will ignore any instance of that file or folder that you specify. For example, on macOS it is common to see the `.DS_STORE` file in a `.gitignore`. This single filename will be matched in all of the folders in local git repo.

More reading about `.gitignore` from the git docs: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

The specific rule about this matching:

> If there is a separator at the beginning or middle (or both) of the pattern, then the pattern is relative to the directory level of the particular .gitignore file itself. Otherwise the pattern may also match at any level below the .gitignore level.